# Async loading scripts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, youtube-api, ejs

[image]i render html pages with js inside through `ejs` like this
 `res.render('search', { data: videos, cookies: cookies });` , and in `html`

```
<div class="video" style="width: 600px; height: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
   <% data.forEach((item, i, data) => {
       let str = '<div class="row my-3"> <div class="col-4"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id + '?autoplay=1&fs=0&controls=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" target="_blank"><img src="' + item.img + '" alt="img" width="200" height="150"></a></div><div class="col-8"><p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id + '?autoplay=1&fs=0&controls=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: underline;">' + item.title + '</a></p><p>' + item.viewCount + ' views</p>' + '<small style="font-weight: bold;"> ' + item.duration + '</small></div></div>'; %>
       <%- str %>
   <% }); %>
</div>
```

browser first waits for the code above to load and then load the page, and i have to wait 2-6sec and only then my page is loading fully. How can i render html and ejs code asynchronously? Thanks for everyone and sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you give an example of what have you created and want do you want to achieve? screenshots will suffice

Comment: @RitoTombe done